# how can I move listbox items to datagridview rows from form2 to form1

Tags: c#

Hi I want to move listbox items to datagridview but I'm getting error can you see where I'm going wrong?

I got 2 form,1 datagridview,2 button ,1 listbox and 1 class ( For moving )

form1, got 2 items ( datagridview and 1 button( to open form 2 ))

form2, got 2 item ( listbox and 1 button( to move items datagridview rows )) I think I've created in your mind what I want to do so far, let me add pictures about application too

[Picture 1 ( Form1 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtSEO.png)

[Picture 2 ( Form2 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdnCz.png)

In class I added the functions for the buttons ( Shows in picture2 ( Button Load (Is ok) |Button Clear (Is ok) |Button Import (where I'm getting error))

well I have one solution for Import button (Below are the form 1 codes you can check)

```
    public static Form1 instance;
    public DataGridView dgv1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
        dgv1 = dataGridView1;
    }
```

Below are the codes of form2 for the solution

```
        private void btnImport_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            int Import = Form1.instance.dgv1.Rows.Add();
            Form1.instance.dgv1.Rows[Import].Cells["Email"].Value = item;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

These codes solve my current problem, but it's very confusing when I want to do it for more than one object, so I want to call my operations by creating a method in class, but I get an error doing so

let me share codes for class

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Sndr01
{
internal class Class1
{

    public string import (ListBox lst , DataGridView dgv)
    {
        childListForm frm = new childListForm();
        string done = lst.ToString();

        foreach (var item in lst.Items)
        {
            int imp = dgv.Rows.Add();
            dgv.Rows[imp].Cells["Email Address"].Value = item.ToString();
            frm.Close();
        }

        return done;
    }
```

here is the my form1 codes

```
    public partial class ListForm : Form
{
    public DataGridView dgvv;

    public ListForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridViewSettings(dgv1);
        dgv1.DataSource = dgvv;
    }
}
```

here is the my form2 codes

```
    public partial class childListForm : Form
{
    ListForm lf = new ListForm();
    DataGridView dgvx;

    public childListForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgvx.DataSource = lf.dgvv.DataSource;
    }


        private void kryptonbtnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        c1.import(lstLeadsbox,dgvx);
    }
}
```

where I'm doing wrong? I'm so confused I would be very grateful if you could help
I may have told you a little too much and bored you, but I wanted to specify the details and not leave any question marks in your mind
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing controls between forms a better way is to have an event to pass data from child to parent form.

In this *generic example* the ListBox is populated with month names. An event is used to pass data to the parent form where the parent form subscribes to the child form event.

**Child form** code

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public delegate void OnPassMonths(string text);
    public event OnPassMonths PassMonths;

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = System.Globalization
            .DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo
            .MonthNames.Take(12)
            .ToList();
    }

    private void PassDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var monthName in (List<string>)listBox1.DataSource)
        {
            PassMonths?.Invoke(monthName);
        }
    }
}
```

In the main form, month names are added only if non-existing using the following extension method to keep code in the form clean and easy to read.

```
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    // in this case the cell is assumed to be 0, change if not 0
    public static bool MonthNotExists(this DataGridView dgv, string month) => 
        dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
                .Equals(month)) == null;
}
```

**Main form** code

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();

        childForm.PassMonths += OnPassMonths;

        try
        {
            childForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        finally
        {
            childForm.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void OnPassMonths(string month)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.MonthNotExists(month))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(month);
        }
    }
}
```